# Prompt user for input in Starburst Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto, starburst

Anyone familiar with Starburst Presto and know how to prompt the user for their input? Can't seem to find anything on it online.

Comment: Are you using a client like pyHive or sqlalchemy ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I'm using Starburst Enterprise